# Brand generator script using multiprocessing

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I have two indices in `Elasticsearch` which are `brands`, and `categories`, and I have a very simple script that generates brands from the `categories` index. I've split my code into separate functions to make it cleaner. I have also benefited from multiprocessor, but I want to know if there is a pythonic way to make my script faster, more effective, and make my code cleaner. Any help would be highly appreciated.

code:

```
"""
Generate brands from categories
"""


from multiprocessing import Pool

from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
from tqdm import tqdm


'''
***
'''
client = Elasticsearch([{'host': '', 'port': 9200}], http_auth=(
    '', ''), timeout=10000000)
brand_ids = []
brands = []
"""
***
"""


def return_category_ids() -> list:
    body = {
        "size": 30000,
        "_source": False
    }
    result = client.search(index="categories", body=body)
    return result["hits"]["hits"]


def return_products_by_category(category) -> list:
    body = {
        "size": 5000000,
        "query": {
            "match": {
                "category.keyword": category["_id"]
            }
        },
        "_source": ["brand_id", "brand"]
    }
    result = client.search(index="products", body=body)
    return result['hits']['hits']


def return_brands_of_product(product) -> bool:
    if (len(product["_source"]["brand_id"]) != 0 and
            product["_source"]["brand_id"] not in brand_ids):
        brands.append({
            "brand_id": product["_source"]["brand_id"],
            "name": product["_source"]["brand"][0]["name"],
            "en_name": product["_source"]["brand"][0]["en_name"]
        })
        brand_ids.append(product["_source"]["brand_id"])
        return True
    return False


def save(category):
    category_id = category["_id"]
    body = {
        "query": {
            "match": {
                "cat_id": category_id
            }
        }
    }

    if len(brands) == 0:
        return f"No brands found for this category: {category_id}"

    try:
        result = client.search(
            index="brands_by_category_from_products",
            body=body
        )

        if result["hits"]["total"]["value"] > 0:
            body = {
                "doc": {
                    "brand_list": brands
                }
            }
            client.update(
                index="brands_by_category_from_products",
                id=result['hits']['hits'][0]['_id'],
                body=body
            )
            return True

        body = {
            "cat_id": category_id,
            "brand_list": brands
        }
        result = client.index(
            index="brands_by_category_from_products",
            doc_type="_doc",
            body=body
        )
        return True
    except Exception:
        return False


if __name__ == '__main__':
    categories = return_category_ids()
    with Pool() as pool:
        products = pool.map(return_products_by_category, tqdm(categories))
```